# Two dimensional Borel Measure proof

Tags: measure-theory, product-measure

A measure on $\mathcal{B}_2$ is called a two dimensional Borel measure. Suppose that $\mu$ and $\nu$ are finite two dimensional Borel measures such that $\mu(A\times B) = \nu(A \times B)$ for all $A,B\in \mathcal{B}$. Prove that $\mu = \nu$. Is this just a uniqueness proof? I ran into this in the book I am using, but I'm not sure what to do here. Can anyone give me a hint on it?

Comment: Hint: Let $\mathcal{A}$ denote the collection of all sets $A$ such that $\mu(A) = \nu(A)$. By hypothesis, you have that $A \times B \in \mathcal{A}$ for all $A,B \in \mathcal{B}$. Can you show that $\mathcal{A}$ contains all the Borel sets? How would you show this?

Comment: @Joe If I was able to show that $\mathcal{A}$ contains all the Borel sets, what would that get me? I think my confusion just comes from not fully understanding what we are trying to prove

Comment: @Joe Careful: it's not at all clear that $\mathcal A$ is closed under unions and intersections. However, it is a [monotone class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_class_theorem).

Comment: @Joey unless I’m misunderstanding the problem, I think you’re trying to show that $\mu(B) = \nu(B)$ for every 2-dimensional Borel set $B \in \mathcal{B}_2$.

Comment: @Joe Yes I think that makes sense to me.